# Underscore _.debounce() : How to execute method only the last time received?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

`_.debounce()` fires at most evevry x milliseconds with `_.debounce(function,x`) .. I want to adapt this to only execute a method `x` millis after the **last** `_.debounce()`.

How do I go about this? (I've read that `$.debounce` does exactly that btw.)

I've tried to do this, but it isn't bullet-proof (not to mention butt-ugly)

```
var timeout;
$(window).on("resize",_.debounce(function(){
  if(timeout){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  }
  //when debounce comes in we cancel it.. this means only the latest debounce actually fires.
  //not bullet proof
  timeout = setTimeout(resizeMap,100);
},50));
```

How to do this elegantly?

Comment: It's kind of confusing what you're after. Can you explain a bit more? Do you want to debounce your debounce? _Yo dawg..._ What you describe seems to be exactly what `debounce` is designed for. Why do you need an additional timeout?

Comment: hehe.. well perhaps it's my browser (infrequent resize events, causing _debounce to be called? testing on Chrome), but while resizing, I keep getting multiple calls to the body of the debounced function. As if it's behaving exactly as _.throttle now I come to think of it.. Weird stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading your comment, this is clearer now.

> well perhaps it's my browser (infrequent resize events, causing _debounce to be called? testing on Chrome), but while resizing, I keep getting multiple calls to the body of the debounced function. As if it's behaving exactly as _.throttle now I come to think of it.. Weird stuff.

50ms is a pretty low debounce time. I'm betting it was working as intended, and you just need a longer debounce time. 50ms is 1/20th of a second. I'm not sure the window resize event fires that quickly. But even if it does, the tiniest pause in mouse movement while resizing could triggers this.

Remove all this `setTimeout` nonsense in your debounced function and set the debounce time to something more like `250` and I bet it will work just like you want.

Answer (score 2):

From http://underscorejs.org/#debounce:

> `_.debounce(function, wait, [immediate])`
>
> Pass `true` for the `immediate` parameter to cause `debounce` to trigger the
>   function on the leading instead of the trailing edge of the *wait*
>   interval. Useful in circumstances like preventing accidental
>   double-clicks on a "submit" button from firing a second time.

So, `$(window).on("resize",_.debounce(resizeMap,100))` should just work.

Comment: Now I'm confused. `_.throttle` per documention "will only actually call the original function at most once per every wait milliseconds". So not once like you desccribe.

Comment: Opps, better forget about that. I have clearly confused them, sorry.